# Unable to display action lightning design icon in visualforce page

Tags: lightning-design-system, svg-icon

I'm trying to use one of the action icons from the lightning design system on my visualforce page. But I'm getting the icon color in black & white.

I have tried to fill color from the CSS too but it's not working.

My code:

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container_circle slds-icon-action-delete" title="Delete">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="iconss">
    <use
    xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}"></use>
  </svg>
</span>
```

I'm getting the following image

[image]

instead, I need like this

[image]

Could someone help to achieve this

Comment: Its a Action icon and as per documentation, they appear only in mobile action bar. Refer this link: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/iconography/#Iconography-Action-Icons-Artboard

Comment: Rohit even if i tried with custom or standard icons it's displaying in black white color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be couple of things which you might not have initialized in your Visualforce page.

1. Enable the lightning style sheet at page level.
2. doctype
3. Specifying these links at page level : `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

I tried the guidelines of Salesforce of incorporating the icons in Visualforce page and it worked. Refer the trailhead example here:[Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_design_system/lightning-design-system2) and  [LDS guidelines for Visualforce page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/). Also refer sample below example which I tried:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
 <title>Salesforce Lightning Design System Trailhead Module</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
 <apex:slds />
</head>
<body>
 <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
 <div class="slds-scope">
 <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
 <div class="myapp">
 <!-- SECTION - BADGE COMPONENTS -->
 <div>
 <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container_circle slds-icon-action-delete" title="Delete icon">
  <svg class="slds-icon" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#delete')}"></use>
  </svg>
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Delete icon</span>
</span>
 </div>

 <!-- / SECTION - BADGE COMPONENTS -->
 </div>
 <!-- / PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
 </div>
 <!-- / REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Follow the steps mentioned by Salesforce in the trailhead.

Comment: Yep, it works like charm. Thanks, I understood the issue with my SLDS class initialization